# How to print value of J/j in case of complex numbers in python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.x

how to get/print value to imaginary part J/j in python3-complex numbers?

I tried using print statement as below-

```
x=2345+4.567J
print(J)
print(x.J)
```

but getting below error in python 3.7-

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       print(J)
>   NameError: name 'J' is not defined
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       print(x.J)
>   AttributeError: 'complex' object has no attribute 'J'

```
>>> x=2345+4.567J
>>> print(J)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#132>", line 1, in <module>
    print(J)
NameError: name 'J' is not defined

>>> print(x.J)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#134>", line 1, in <module>
    print(x.J)
AttributeError: 'complex' object has no attribute 'J'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create another complex number with `x.imag` as the imaginary part and `0` as the real part:

```
>>> x=2345+4.567J
>>> print(complex(0, x.imag))
4.567j
```

Or, use string formatting if it's just for display:

```
>>> x=2345+4.567J
>>> print('{}j'.format(x.imag))
4.567j
```

Comment: sir i need to get/print vale of j/J (which is assumed square-root of -1 ) not imaginary part value. suggest for this....

Comment: @Puneet `j` is the square-root of `-1`, that's it, it has no _real_ value with decimals like real numbers do, it's just defined such that: `j² = -1`. Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) and [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:complex/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:complex-num/a/intro-to-complex-numbers) for more info on complex numbers.

Comment: I know that square of j = -1 in complex numbers but my requirement is to print value of J/j on python3.7 shell prompt(>>>). How can we do it??

Comment: @Puneet I don't understand what you mean by _print the value of j/J_? What do you think its value is? What is the expected output?

Comment: j/J pre-defined value in python system is square-root of -1.My expected output should be its value only. How to print value of j/J in case of complex numbers in python3.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "imag" attribute

```
>>> print(x.imag)
4.567
```

Comment: >>> print (x.imag) will print imaginary part value not value of j/J
4.567